# system.out.print doesn't display while running code?

Tags: java

I've stumbled upon a strange error whenever I run my Java program.

The code is as follows

```
interface meth{
int prime(int x);
int div3(int x);
int div8(int x);
int divall(int x);
}

class Cal implements meth{
int x; 
int z;
 public int prime(int x){
     return (x/x)*(x/1);
 }
 public int div3(int x){
     return x%3;
 }
 public int div8(int x){
     return x%8;
 }
 public int divall(int x){
     if((x%3)==0){
         if((x%8)==0){ z=2;}
     }
     else {z=1;}
     return z;
 }

}
public class Math {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cal val = new Cal();

    System.out.println("This program will output " +
            "numbers that are: Prime, divisible " +
            "by 3, and divisible by 8, but not " +
            "divisible by both 3 and 8");
    for(int i=1; i==2500; i++)
        if(val.prime(i)==i){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        else if(val.divall(i)==2){
            break;
        }
        else if(val.div3(i)==0){
            System.out.println(i + "");
        }
        else if(val.div8(i)==0){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
}

}
```

It compiles just fine. But when it runs, instead of displaying only the numbers that are prime, divisible by 3, and divisible by 8, it only displays the first *system.out.println* stating the purpose of the program. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Also, I know the use of *interface* and separate classes may be a bit excessive. I was just practicing new ideas taught in the current chapter of my class.

Comment: Look at the condition of your `for` loop

Comment: Then check out your prime method because it's a bit strange, and won't work, even if you do get the for loop going.

Comment: The second expression in a `for` tells the program when the loop will keep going, not when the loop will stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because a `for` loop uses this format:

```
for(initialization; boolean_expression; update){
  //do this
}
```

The problem is, the `boolean_expression` part of your loop will never be true. You're doing:

```
for(int i=1; i==2500; i++)
```

Your for loop starts out with the initialization `i = 1`. `i` cannot be `2500` and `1` at the same time. What you should be doing is this:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 2500; i++){
  //do something here
}
```

This will run while `i <= 2500`, and add 1 to `i` every time it loops, making it run `2,500` times.

Also, another thing I noticed is that you don't have curly-brackets in your for loop, so it loops, but never does anything. You should add `{}` curly-brackets to your for loop, just like you would do for an `if` statement.

So, your for loop should look like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 2500; i++){
    if(val.prime(i)==i){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    else if(val.divall(i)==2){
        break;
    }
    else if(val.div3(i)==0){
        System.out.println(i + "");
    }
    else if(val.div8(i)==0){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your swift input. It helped a lot. I feel so stupid for missing something so simple. The numbers are now displaying. Although, as Hovercraft Full Of Eels stated, my prime number method doesn't work. Thanks again for your support!

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=1; i==2500; i++)
```

to

```
for(int i=1; i < 2500; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything in your for loop is never going to run because the for loop's condition is impossible to meet: i will be 1, and for no iteration will it ever be == to 2500.